# ios - Every time application:openURL:sourceapplication is fired, iCloud backup size increase

Tags: iphone, ios, size, icloud, openurl

I have an app that opens different files.
To avoid the app to be reject from Apple, only user data must be backed up on iCloud.
I have done all to meet "iOS Data Storage Guidelines" requirements.

But I can't resolve this issue:
Every time the method
application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:
is fired, the iCloud size for my app increase for exactly the file size.

For testing, now when the openURL method is fired, I simply return YES, so my app do nothing with the incoming URL, but the size still increase.

A summary of what is happening (Example is opening a mail attachment of 3 mb from mail app):
- Actual size of the app on iCloud: 3Mb
- Tap on attachment
- Choose to open with my app
- openURL event is fired
- openURL return YES WITHOUT DOING ANYTHING ELSE
- Actual size of the app on iCloud: 6Mb

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
Claudio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is being copied over from the email application's sandbox into your application's sandbox. You can see exactly where it is by looking at the URL component. Most likely you will want to iCloud exclude the file (I recommend moving it into a folder that already has this flag set) and be sure to clean the file up if you no longer have a need for it in your app.

Comment: The URL does not refer to my app but the mail app: @file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/512...F6BE/Documents/Inbox/Filename.pdf,

Comment: Ok, my mistake, the file is in my app. I'll try to move it in another folder.